# Не могу подтянуть значение из dict. В чем ошибка?

Tags: python, dict

```
from typing import Dict, Any
Sweet: Dict[Any, int] = dict(Plain=0, Vanilla=5, ChocolateChips=5, Strawberry=10, Chocolate=10)
class IceCream:
    def __init__(self, flavor, sprinkles ):
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.sprinkles = sprinkles
        self.sweetness = dict.get(self.flavor)  #+self.sprinkles#for flavor in self.flavor#
    def get_sweetness(self):
        return self.sweetness
    
ice1 = IceCream("Chocolate", 13)
ice2 = IceCream("Vanilla", 0)
ice3 = IceCream("Strawberry", 15)
#sweetest_icecream([ice1, ice2, ice3])
print(ice1.get_sweetness())
```

Answer (score 2):

так вы обращайтесь к своему объекту, а не к абстрактному dict:

```
        self.sweetness = Sweet.get(self.flavor)  #+self.sprinkles#for flavor in self.flavor#
```